# How to generate this kind of xmonad tiling

Tags: xmonad

How can I generate this kind of tiling with xmonad?

http://xmonad.org/images/screen-ejt-spiral-dzen.png

I know you can increase/decrease the number of windows in the master pane with **mod-comma**, and use **mod-space** **mod-h** and **mod-l** to change the layout. But it seems like just those set of commands cannot reproduce the kind of tiling in the above link.

In particular, there are two things I just don't know how to do that the link above does:

1. The larger tile on the right is not split horizontally in the middle, but is actually longer. I can only increase/decrease the master pane like that using **mod-h** and **mod-l**
2. The smaller tile on the right is split into two subtiles. I have no idea how you would even go about this with xmonad

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a new layout in your .xmonad/xmonad.hs 
For this you need to have a little experience with haskell.

I've created a fullscreen Layout which can be used by pressing a specific key combination here's an example:

import the following:

```
import XMonad.Layout.Spacing
import XMonad.Layout.LayoutCombinators hiding ( (|||) )
import XMonad.Layout.Fullscreen
import XMonad.Layout.NoBorders
import XMonad.Layout.Reflect
import XMonad.Layout.Combo
import XMonad.Layout.TwoPane
import XMonad.Layout.Tabbed 
import XMonad.Layout.PerWorkspace
import XMonad.Layout.IM
import XMonad.Layout.ThreeColumns
```

And then you could do something like this:

```
sPx = 1

verticalLayout = spacing sPx $ avoidStruts $ reflectHoriz $ Tall 1 0.03 0.5
verticalLayoutLargeScreen = spacing sPx $ avoidStruts $ ThreeCol 1 0.03 0.5
horizontalLayout = spacing sPx $ avoidStruts $ Mirror $ Tall 1 0.03 0.5
webdevLayout = spacing sPx $ avoidStruts $ Tall 1 0.03 0.63
fullscreenLayout = noBorders $ fullscreenFull $ Full

myLayout =
    onWorkspace "2:web" (webdevLayout ||| fullscreenLayout) $
                    (verticalLayout ||| horizontalLayout ||| fullscreenLayout)
```

After this define a mapping for your key combo:

```
myAdditionalKeys = [
  -- Switch to next layout:
  ((mod4Mask .|. shiftMask, xK_m), sendMessage NextLayout),
]
```

and then do not forget to add your layout and your key Mapping to the config, could look like this:

```
main = do
  xmonad $ defaultConfig
             { manageHook = manageSpawn <+> myManageHook <+> manageDocks,
               layoutHook = myLayout,
               logHook = dynamicLogWithPP xmobarPP {
                       ppOutput = hPutStrLn xmproc,
                       ppLayout = (\ x -> ""),
                       ppTitle = xmobarColor "#b2ed00" ""
                     } >> updatePointer (Relative 0.99 0.99),
               modMask = mod4Mask,
               borderWidth = 4,
               normalBorderColor = "#777777",
               focusedBorderColor = "#ccff00",
               workspaces = myWorkspaces,
               focusFollowsMouse = True,
               terminal = "x-terminal-emulator"
             }
             `removeKeys` myRemoveKeys
             `additionalKeys` myAdditionalKeys
```

Comment: Thanks, yeah I guess the docs didn't make it clear enough that that particular layout can't be done with keys but needs a custom layout.